# Logback - Reentrant Lock?

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

We are using logback as our logging impl. There is this Reentrant lock that is causing performance problems. Any idea of why this could occur ?

Here is one invocation trace where we see high as 9.5 sec for lock. Please find attached the complete trace.

```
FrameworkServlet.service:unknown (160ms self time, 36258 ms total time)
HttpServlet.service:621 (0ms self time, 36098 ms total time)
  DispatcherServlet.doService:838 (0ms self time, 31639 ms total time)
   DispatcherServlet.doDispatch:910 (0ms self time, 30835 ms total time)
    Logger.log:788 (0ms self time, 9485 ms total time)
     Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus:396 (0ms self time, 9485 ms total time)
      Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend:442 (0ms self time, 9485 ms total time)
       Logger.callAppenders:260 (0ms self time, 9485 ms total time)
        Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders:273 (0ms self time, 9485 ms total time)
         AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders:48 (0ms self time, 9485 ms total time)
          UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend:88 (0ms self time, 9485 ms total time)
           OutputStreamAppender.append:103 (0ms self time, 9485 ms total time)
            OutputStreamAppender.subAppend:217 (0ms self time, 9485 ms total time)
             ReentrantLock.lock:290 (9485ms self time, 9485 ms total time)
```

Image Attached :
[image: Reentrant lock]

Comment: Looks like several thread write to log simultaneously and very intensively.

Comment: Will write to log file is done under lock. It could IO issue, when one thread is writing to file system very slowly and another thread is waiting for 1 thread

Comment: So what is the solution ? Should we use Async appenders in logback ? How can this be avoided ?

Comment: It is not `ReentrantLock` issue only logging layer delay. Are you using some kind of socket appender? Writing to a file (here to stream) is a bottleneck and all logging threads needs to wait for eachother. Logging itself (at least appending new entries to the same output) needs to by serialized as it would create corrupted logs/mixed logs.

Comment: We are using ConsoleApender and FileAppender. So do we have to use a different appender for this to be serialized ?

Comment: Solution - figure out why writing to log file takes so much time. It's not about lock, it's about delay when writing to log file. Maybe you have FS issue